# change readonly property onfocus of that field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field with type="password". Due to some reasons, I have made the field readonly. And idea is onfocus - I will remove the readonly attribute.

Currently when I do the following I get the alert onfocus

```
<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="function hi()
{alert ('hi')}; hi()" readonly>
```

but below code for onclick does not work:

```
  onclick="function hi(){$(this).removeAttr('readonly');};hi()"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `onclick="this.removeAttribute('readonly')"`

Answer (score 3):

Though I don't understand the need of `readonly` when eventually you are going to edit the data of that input, but if you want to do it, you can use following methods

with Jquery

`<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');" readonly>`

---

With vanilla JS

`<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="this.removeAttribute('readonly')" readonly>`

```css
input[readonly] {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');" readonly>

<br><br>

<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="this.removeAttribute('readonly')" readonly>
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent the manage passwords prompt (the one with saved password suggestions to open everytime I click on password input field) So I thought of making it readonly first and then onfocus I would make it editable, but in someway that would prevent the prompt. Bad idea. Does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't forget `onfocusout="this.setAttribute('readonly','');"`, or the password pop-up will return on second click of the field.

Answer (score 0):

attach the click listener via javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('pt').addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.removeAttribute('readonly');
});
```

but it's better to use focus and blur events:

```js
document.getElementById('pt').addEventListener('focus',function(){
      this.removeAttribute('readonly');
    });
document.getElementById('pt').addEventListener('blur',function(){
      this.setAttribute('readonly','');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="$('#pt').attr('readonly', false);" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving it to a seperate function for readability:

```
<input type="password" id="pt" onclick="hi()" readonly>
```

```
function hi() {
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
}
```